# Is there a Kotlin coroutine channel that behaves like XStream Stream?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I want a coroutine channel that behaves like [XStream `Stream`](https://github.com/staltz/xstream/blob/master/README.md)

1. `send` to the channel are always non-blocking
2. There is no buffer and values are "lost" if there is no receiver.
3. New subscribers *do not* get the last value.
4. All subscribers receive all values (like [BroadcastChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/-broadcast-channel/index.html))

The closest I find is [ConflatedBroadcastChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/index.html), however this "remembers" the last value which makes it like [XStream MemoryStream](https://github.com/staltz/xstream/blob/master/README.md#memorystream).

Is there a workaround to get my exact semantics?

Answer (score 1):

No, there aren't any channels like this, feel free to [create an issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues).

The closest workaround you can have is to provide an extension on `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` which will discard existing element:

```
fun <T> ConflatedBroadcastChannel<T>.subscription(): ReceiveChannel<T> {
    val subscription = openSubscription()
    subscription.poll()
    return subscription
}
```

From the consumer point of view, this subscription has the same semantics as `XStream`, but it doesn't comply "There is no buffer" part: sent element will be preserved in memory (~can't be garbage collected) until next `send` is called.